# Intersection of two independent sigma-algebras is trivial sigma-algebra?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Is the intersection of two independent $\sigma$-algebras the trivial $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. $\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$)?

My attempt: yes.
Let $P$ and $Q$ be two independent $\sigma$-algebras. Then for any set $A\in P\cap Q$, by independence, we have
$$P(A\cap A)=P(A)P(A).$$
That is, $P(A)=1$ or $0$. Since only the whole space $\Omega$ has measure $1$ and empty set has measure $0$, we have $P\cap Q=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ (here i'm not so certain).

Comment: Are you sure that $P(A) = 0 \Rightarrow A = \emptyset$? Can't there be a nonempty set with measure 0?

Comment: moreover there may be sets with full measure that are not $\Omega$. In general, we know that $\{\emptyset , \Omega \} \subset P \cap Q$, but the other inclusion is generally not true.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. Consider a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathsf{P})$ and let $\mathcal{G}$ be the collection of $\mathsf{P}$-trivial events of $\mathcal{F}$, i.e.
$$
\mathcal{G}=\{F\in \mathcal{F}:\mathsf{P}(F)\in \{0,1\}\}.
$$
Then $\mathcal{G}$ is independent of any sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$. In particular, it is independent of $\mathcal{F}$. So $\mathcal{G}\cap \mathcal{F}\ne \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ unless $\mathcal{G}$ is a trivial $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Thank you! Then under your setting, is it true if I say $P\cap Q\subset\{F\in\mathcal{F}:P(F)\in\{0,1\}\}$?